# why my `delete where id in` statement drop all records in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I am using MySQL version 5.7.24. I want to delete records with same ex_id and ex_type in reply table:

```
CREATE TABLE `reply` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `ex_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `ex_type` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_ex_id_type` (`ex_id`,`ex_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

having following data:

```
+----+-------------------+-------+---------+
| id | content           | ex_id | ex_type |
+----+-------------------+-------+---------+
|  1 | this is a content |     1 |       1 |
|  2 | this a test       |     2 |       1 |
|  3 | this a contet     |     1 |       1 |
|  4 | the 4th content   |     3 |       1 |
+----+-------------------+-------+---------+
```

Record 1 and 3 share the same ex_id and ex_type, of those I want to delete the record with smaller id (the record 1), so I wrote the following query:

```
delete from reply where id in (
    select id from (
        select min(id) from reply group by ex_type and ex_id having count(1) > 1
    ) tmp
)
-- Query OK, 4 rows affected
```

This was supposed to delete one record but instead all records are deleted.

Actually there is a mistake in this SQL, the inner SQL `select min(id) from reply group by ex_type and ex_id having count(1) > 1` return the result with only field: 'min(id)', outer sql `select id from () tmp` selects a non exsit field id which lead to an error, but MySQL still executes this sql and delete all records.

I want to know why this happened.

Comment: What result do you get after running the query: `select min(id) from reply group by ex_type and ex_id having count(1) > 1`

Comment: I'm not sure what happens with `group by ex_type and ex_id`, I'm assuming its equivalent to `group by true` ? I think the syntax you're looking for is `group by ex_type, ex_id`. Maybe that will fix your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...outer sql `select id from () tmp` selects a non exsit field id
>   which lead to an error, but mysql execute this sql and delete all
>   records.
>
> I want to konw why this happened.

This subquery will not run on its own:

```
select id from (
    select min(id) from reply group by ex_type and ex_id having count(1) > 1
) tmp
/* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' */
```

But when it is run inside a subquery then according to scope resolution rules ***the id column resolves to the id column of the outer query since the requested column is not present in the FROM clause***. The query is essentially like:

```
delete from reply where id in (
    select reply.id from (
        select min(id) from reply group by ex_type and ex_id having count(1) > 1
    ) tmp
)
/* Affected rows: 4  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.031 sec. */
```

The condition is true for all rows since 1 IN (1), 2 IN (2), 3 IN (3)... are all true. Fixing the typo (`group by ex_type and ex_id`) will not fix the problem, change your query to this:

```
delete from reply where id in (
    select tmp.id from (
        select min(id) as id from reply group by ex_type, ex_id having count(1) > 1
    ) tmp
)
```

Comment: Scope resolution rules: the id column resolves to the id column of the outer query can really explain why this happens, your answer help me a lot, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your query is logically wrong.
This part:

```
select min(id) from reply group by ex_type and ex_id having count(1) > 1
```

groups by `ex_type and ex_id`  instead of `ex_type, ex_id`.
Most important, it does not return a column named/aliased as `id`.
So that:

```
select id from...
```

actually refers to the table's `id` and returns **all** the `id`s of the table and the result is that all the rows are deleted.
You can see this behavior [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p3MWZUvMtts1D1fLiHopwu/1).
I believe that this is what you want to do:

```
delete from reply where id in 
(
    select id from (
        select min(id) id from reply group by ex_type, ex_id having count(*) > 1
    ) tmp
);
```

Comment: Is the `id` alias really necessary? Your fiddle works just fine without it

Comment: Do you mean `select min(id) id`? No it does not work without it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p3MWZUvMtts1D1fLiHopwu/2

Comment: I meant this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nmonQLGVsd6gvCEVSxJu8x/1 Edit: nevermind, it doesn't work for a `DELETE`, my apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting - this seems to be a bug, because the DELETE should fail in this instance!!

Anyway, just attach an alias to min(id) (and remove that strange 'and' before the GROUP BY), and everything will be fine... (although, I wouldn't write this query this way)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reply;

CREATE TABLE `reply` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `ex_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `ex_type` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_ex_id_type` (`ex_id`,`ex_type`)
);

INSERT INTO reply VALUES
(1,'this is a content',1,1),
(2,'this a test',2,1),
(3,'this a contet',1,1),
(4,'the 4th content',3,1);


delete from reply where id in 
(
    select id from (
        select min(id) id from reply group by ex_type, ex_id having count(1) > 1
    ) tmp
);

SELECT * FROM reply;
+----+-----------------+-------+---------+
| id | content         | ex_id | ex_type |
+----+-----------------+-------+---------+
|  2 | this a test     |     2 |       1 |
|  3 | this a contet   |     1 |       1 |
|  4 | the 4th content |     3 |       1 |
+----+-----------------+-------+---------+
```

FWIW, for a small data set, I'd probably write that query this way...

```
DELETE r 
  FROM reply r
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(id) id 
         FROM reply 
        GROUP 
           BY ex_type
            , ex_id 
       HAVING COUNT(0) > 1
     ) x
    ON x.id = r.id
```